# How can I make a thin Angular/Typescript wrapper for an external library without too much duplication?

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to write a service wrapper for an external library so that I can inject it into various components in my app. My current code looks something like this:

```
import * as externalLibrary from 'widgetManager';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class WidgetService {
  realService: externalLibrary.Service;

  constructor() {
    this.realService = new externalLibrary.Service();
  }

  create(params) {
    this.realService.create(params);
  }

  read(params) {
    this.realService.read(params);
  }

  update(params) {
    this.realService.update(params);
  }

  delete(params) {
    this.realService.delete(params);
  }

}
```

The real library has a lot more methods than above, but generally I just want to write my class a "thin wrapper" which passes the arguments straight through untouched. How can I do this without writing repetitive definitions for every method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to create a wrapper class. You just need to make it injectable.

```
export const SERVICE = new InjectionToken<externalLibrary.Service>('Service');

@NgModule({
    providers: [
        {
            provide: SERVICE, 
            useValue: new externalLibrary.Service()
    ]
});
```

Then you can use it.

```
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent {
    public constructor(@Inject(SERVICE) service: externalLibrary.Service) {
        // more code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. And what if I want to shorten `externalLibrary.Service` into a single token, like `externalLibService`? Is there a way to accomplish that?

Comment: @Stewart you can create a token and use that. You don't have to provide the TypeScript type. You can just use any if you want.